How to fill area between curves in 3D plot in Julia using Makie?
I'm trying to create a 3D fakewaterfall plot using the Makie package in Julia. Therefore i plot multiple spectra, each shifted along the y-axis, in a 3D axis. I got that working, but now i want to fill the area between every spectrum and the x-axis.
My minimal working example provides the waterfall plot, but is missing the part on how to fill the area.
In 2D plots i used fill_between!(ax,x,y,0), but i dont know how or if this also works in 3D Plots.
I'm using Julia v1.9.4, Makie v0.21.3 and CairoMakie v0.12.7.
Any guidance would be appreciated!
Right now it looks like this,

but i want it to look like this:

using CairoMakie

# Example Data
    spectra = [sin.(1:0.1:10) for _ in 1:10]
    x_values = 1:0.1:10

# Figure
    fig = Figure()

# 3D-Axis
    ax = Axis3(fig[1, 1], title="Waterfallplot", xlabel="X-Axis", ylabel="Y-Axis", zlabel="Z-Axis")

# Plot Data
    for (i, spectrum) in enumerate(spectra)
        y_shift = i  # Shift along y-axis
        points = Point3.(x_values, y_shift,  spectrum)  # Data to Point3
        lines!(ax, points, linewidth=2)  # Plot each spectrum
    end

# Show figure
    fig
# Example Data
    spectra = [sin.(1:0.1:10) for _ in 1:10]
    x_values = 1:0.1:10

# Figure
    fig = Figure()

# 3D-Axis
    ax = Axis3(fig[1, 1], title="Waterfallplot", xlabel="X-Axis", ylabel="Y-Axis", zlabel="Z-Axis")

# Plot Data
    for (i, spectrum) in enumerate(spectra)
        y_shift = i  # Shift along y-axis
        points = Point3.(x_values, y_shift,  spectrum)  # Data to Point3
        lines!(ax, points, linewidth=2)  # Plot each spectrum
    end

# Show figure
    fig# Example Data
    spectra = [sin.(1:0.1:10) for _ in 1:10]
    x_values = 1:0.1:10

# Figure
    fig = Figure()

# 3D-Axis
    ax = Axis3(fig[1, 1], title="Waterfallplot", xlabel="X-Axis", ylabel="Y-Axis", zlabel="Z-Axis")

# Plot Data
    for (i, spectrum) in enumerate(spectra)
        y_shift = i  # Shift along y-axis
        points = Point3.(x_values, y_shift,  spectrum)  # Data to Point3
        lines!(ax, points, linewidth=2)  # Plot each spectrum
    end

# Show figure
    fig# Example Data
    spectra = [sin.(1:0.1:10) for _ in 1:10]
    x_values = 1:0.1:10

# Figure
    fig = Figure()

# 3D-Axis
    ax = Axis3(fig[1, 1], title="Waterfallplot", xlabel="X-Axis", ylabel="Y-Axis", zlabel="Z-Axis")

# Plot Data
    for (i, spectrum) in enumerate(spectra)
        y_shift = i  # Shift along y-axis
        points = Point3.(x_values, y_shift,  spectrum)  # Data to Point3
        lines!(ax, points, linewidth=2)  # Plot each spectrum
    end

# Show figure
    fig


When you say you want to fill between each curve and the X axis, do you mean between the curve and the X-Y plane? Filling to the X axis would make all the fillings overlap, resulting in a solid ribbon which loses distinctions between the curves you show and so I think is not what you would want.  If you want instead to fill to the XY plane, then you probably want a contour3d plot.

Sorry for not beeing clear in what i want.
I appended a 2nd graph to my original post, so i makes it more clear what i want.
With the contour3d plot, i get a surface so all the spectra are connected, this is not what i want.

I found a way of doing it:

using CairoMakie

# Example Data
    spectra = [sin.(1:0.1:10) for _ in 1:7]
    x_values = 1:0.1:10

# Figure
    fig = Figure()

# 3D-Axis
    ax = Axis3(fig[1, 1], title="Waterfallplot", xlabel="X-Axis", ylabel="Y-Axis", zlabel="Z-Axis")

# Plot Data
    for i in 7:-1:1
        y_shift = i-1  # Shift along y-axis
        points = Point3.(x_values, y_shift,  spectra[i])  # Data to Point3
        base   = Point3.(x_values, y_shift, minimum(spectra[i]))
        band!(ax, base, points,alpha=0.5,color=Makie.wong_colors()[i])  # Plot each spectrum
        lines!(ax, points, linewidth=2,color=Makie.wong_colors()[i])  # Plot each spectrum
    end
# Show figure
    fig

